# How to find the htpasswd file created for SVN over Apache?

Tags: files, find, apache-httpd, subversion

I setup subversion with remote access over apache. I created an `htpasswd` file for it, but now I've forgotten the filename and path. How can I find it?

Comment: Please update your question with: OS+major/minor version, Apache-httpd version.

Comment: If SVN is using it, it must be listed in one of the sites-enabled files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file has to be located in the svn htdocs directory tree and there has to be a reference in the configuration as well.

But if you do at least remember a part of the content of the file (e.g. a username) you can search beginning at your DocumentRoot-directory:

`grep -RI "$USERNAME" $DOCROOT/*`